# Android Development Issues in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to build an android application in eclipse. My issue in detail is as follows:

1. I first setup the sdk and adt plugin along with the svn for eclipse.
2. Then I imported an existing svn trunk from (File->Import->Checkout projects from SVN).
3. Then I face the following errors:

   a. Project has no default.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
   b. None of import files are being resolved. It includes java.io, and all the basic java classes. I checked the Compiler Compliance level too.. It is set to 1.6
   c. When I check into project properties for the issue, under Java Build Path: I find "Build path is entry missing: Projectname/gen"
   Then in the libraries tab i find: "Unable to get System Library for the project".

It would be really nice if some one can throw some light on this issue. plz let me know if u need any more description.

Thanks,
Maverick gugu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check out .classpath and .project files from svn to? My usual scenario is to checkout files from version control and then Create New Project->Android-> Create from existing sources.Usually it works OK.

Comment: You also have to make sure that you haven't placed the source you are importing in the current workspace directory or you will get an error when trying to create/import a new project.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. How can I verify where the .classpath and .project  are checked out?

Comment: @Maverickgugu: Try to make fresh checkout from version control and create android project way I've described. If .project and .classpath are already there there will be an error message on new project wizard, but based on your problem description it looks like there were no eclipse meta info so svn checkout wizard tried to figure it out on it's own and failed. Hope it helps

Comment: Hey thanks!! I found the .project and .classpath. but when i create from existing sources in the same workspace, "An Eclipse project already exists in this directory. Consider using File > Import > Existing Project instead."